# Get selected subcommand with argparse

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

When I use subcommands with python argparse, I can get the selected arguments.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-g', '--global')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()   
foo_parser = subparsers.add_parser('foo')
foo_parser.add_argument('-c', '--count')
bar_parser = subparsers.add_parser('bar')
args = parser.parse_args(['-g', 'xyz', 'foo', '--count', '42'])
# args => Namespace(global='xyz', count='42')
```

So `args` doesn't contain `'foo'`.  Simply writing `sys.argv[1]` doesn't work because of the possible global args. How can I get the subcommand itself?

Answer (score 245, accepted):

The very bottom of the [Python docs on argparse sub-commands](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) explains how to do this:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('-g', '--global')
>>> subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest="subparser_name") # this line changed
>>> foo_parser = subparsers.add_parser('foo')
>>> foo_parser.add_argument('-c', '--count')
>>> bar_parser = subparsers.add_parser('bar')
>>> args = parser.parse_args(['-g', 'xyz', 'foo', '--count', '42'])
>>> args
Namespace(count='42', global='xyz', subparser_name='foo')
```

You can also use the `set_defaults()` method referenced just above the example I found.

Comment: I also like to add `required=True` to force users to use a subcommand.

Comment: Note, there might be a non-obvious problem: if you execute `.add_argument('--subparser_name')`, i.e. add an argument whose name matches the `dest` one, then value of that argument *(if passed)* will overwrite the name of the parser. I think such problematic configuration should really be detected by argparse, but unfortunately it isn't.

Answer (score 35):

[`ArgumentParser.add_subparsers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers) has `dest` formal argument described as:

> `dest` - name of the attribute under which sub-command name will be stored; by default `None` and no value is stored

In the example below of a simple task function layout using subparsers, the selected subparser is in `parser.parse_args().subparser`.

```
import argparse


def task_a(alpha):
    print('task a', alpha)


def task_b(beta, gamma):
    print('task b', beta, gamma)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='subparser')

    parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('task_a')
    parser_a.add_argument(
        '-a', '--alpha', dest='alpha', help='Alpha description')

    parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('task_b')
    parser_b.add_argument(
        '-b', '--beta', dest='beta', help='Beta description')
    parser_b.add_argument(
        '-g', '--gamma', dest='gamma', default=42, help='Gamma description')

    kwargs = vars(parser.parse_args())
    globals()[kwargs.pop('subparser')](**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to post this answer as this came in very handy in some of my recent work. This method makes use of decorators (although not used with conventional @ syntax) and comes in especially handy if the recommended `set_defaults` is already being used with subparsers.

```
import argparse
from functools import wraps
import sys

def foo(subparser):
    subparser.error('err')

def bar(subparser):
    subparser.error('err')

def map_subparser_to_func(func, subparser):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(subparser, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

foo_parser = subparsers.add_parser('foo')
foo_parser.set_defaults(func = map_subparser_to_func(foo, foo_parser))

bar_parser = subparsers.add_parser('bar')
bar_parser.set_defaults(func = map_subparser_to_func(bar, bar_parser))

args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
args.func()
```

The `map_subparser_to_func` function can be modified to set the subparser to some class attribute or global variable inside of the `wrapper` function instead of passing it directly and can also be reworked to a conventional decorator for the functions, although that would require adding another layer.

This way there is a direct reference to the object.

Answer (score 0):

I have nested subparsers and wanted to get the selected
subparser object so I can `subparser.error(..)` on special cases
where `parse_known_args()` has invalid unknown args.

I came up with this recursion to solve it. It might only cover
my specific case of subparsers nested with subparsers with
each of them using an explicit `dest`. But it has the advantage
that it doesn't require using `set_defaults` and that it gets
the actual subparser object, not just the name of it.

```py
def get_selected_subparser(parser, args):
    for action in parser._actions:
        if not isinstance(action, argparse._SubParsersAction): continue
        choice = getattr(args, action.dest)
        if choice is None:
            return None
        else:
            subparser = action.choices[choice]
            return get_selected_subparser(subparser, args) or subparser
    else:
        return None
```

Now I can do this to print the usage info of the selected subparser:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser( ... )  
#  ... definition of parser goes here
args, remainder = parser.parse_known_args()
if remainder_is_invalid():
    subparser = get_selected_subparser(parser, args)
    subparser.error("unrecognized arguments: {}".format(" ".join(remainder)))
```