# Python argparse, provide different arguments based on parent argument value

Tags: python, dynamic, argparse, subparsers

here is what i would like to do :
A command that looks like git command behavior. You don't get the same options whether you typed git commit or git checkout.
But in my case i want to provide different arguments based on an argument value (a file name) like this :

```
>cmd file.a -h
usage: cmd filename [-opt1] [-opt2]
positional arguments:
filename         file to process
optional arguments:
-opt1            do something on files of type 'a'
-opt2            do something else on files of type 'a'

>cmd file.b -h
usage: cmd filename [-opt3] [-opt4] 
positional arguments:
filename         file to process
optional arguments:
-opt3            do something on files of type 'b'
-opt4            do something else on files of type 'b'
```

Is it possible to do this kind of thing using python and argparse ?
What i've tried so far is :

```
parser = argparse.Argument_parser(prog='cmd')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

parser.add_argument('filename', 
                    help="file or sequence to process")

args = parser.parse_args(args=argv[1:])

sub_parser = subparsers.add_parser(args.filename, help="job type")
base, ext = os.path.splitext(args.filename)
if ext == 'a':
    sub_parser.add_argument("-opt1", action='store_true')
    sub_parser.add_argument("-opt2", action='store_true')
elif ext == 'b':
    sub_parser.add_argument("-opt3", action='store_true')
    sub_parser.add_argument("-opt4", action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args(args=argv[1:])
```

I don't know if i should use subparsers or child parsers or groups, i'm kind of lost in all the possibilities provided by argparse

Comment: Based on the behavior you want to see, it sounds as if a subparser is the way you want to go.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

When you take a look at [`parse_args()` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.2/Lib/argparse.py) you'll notice that it parses all arguments at once (it doesn't use `yield` to continuously generate state) so you have to prepare your structure before and not after half of the arguments would be parsed.

[Taking from official example in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) you should add subparser(s) before starting parsing like this:

```python
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help')

# create the parser for the "a" command
parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('a', help='a help')
parser_a.add_argument("--opt1", action='store_true')
parser_a.add_argument("--opt2", action='store_true')

# create the parser for the "b" command
parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('b', help='b help')
parser_b.add_argument("--opt3", action='store_true')
parser_b.add_argument("--opt4", action='store_true')

# parse some argument lists
print(parser.parse_args())
```

And the output (in command line), help is nicely printed:

```
D:\tmp>s.py -h
usage: PROG [-h] {a,b} ...

positional arguments:
  {a,b}       sub-command help
    a         a help
    b         b help

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

*A* arguments are parsed

```
D:\tmp>s.py a --opt1
Namespace(opt1=True, opt2=False)
```

*B* arguments are parsed

```
D:\tmp>s.py b
Namespace(opt3=False, opt4=False)
```

Also with args:

```
D:\tmp>s.py b --opt3
Namespace(opt3=True, opt4=False)
```

Running *A* arguments in *B* causes error:

```
D:\tmp>s.py b --opt2
usage: PROG [-h] {a,b} ...
PROG: error: unrecognized arguments: --opt2
```

---

Also if you need to [identify which subparser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4575792/1149736) was used you may add `dest=name` to `parser.add_subparsers()` call (*which I think isn't properly stressed in the docs*):

```python
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help', dest='subparser_name')
```

With the result of:

```python
D:\tmp>s.py b --opt3
Namespace(opt3=True, opt4=False, subparser_name='b')
```

---

If you needed to really create arguments dynamically (for example load some argument options from *expensive* resource) you could use [`parse_known_args()`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args):

> Sometimes a script may only parse a few of the command-line arguments, passing the remaining arguments on to another script or program. In these cases, the `parse_known_args()` method can be useful. It works much like `parse_args()`except that it does not produce an error when extra arguments are present. Instead, **it returns a two item *tuple* containing the populated namespace and the *list* of remaining argument strings**.

After all, `parse_args()` just checks trailing aruments:

```python
def parse_args(self, args=None, namespace=None):
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
    if argv:
        msg = _('unrecognized arguments: %s')
        self.error(msg % ' '.join(argv))
    return args
```

And then you can re-execute another parser on `argv`, but I can imagine few issues that can go with this and I wouldn't recommend it until *really* necessary.

Comment: Awesome answer. Enjoy your new badge.

Comment: Reread it again. Still layers of awesomeness to uncover here :)