# Using only one argument in argparse for multiple cases

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

```
$ script.py status
$ script.py terminate
$ script.py tail /tmp/some.log
```

As you can see the script can perform 3 tasks. The last task requires an additional argument (path of the file).

I want to use add_argument only once like below.

```
parser.add_argument("command")
```

And then check what command was requested by user and create conditionals based upon the same. If the command is tail I need to access the next argument (file path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to create a [sub-parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers) for each command. This way it is extendable if those other commands also need arguments at some point. Something like this:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true', help='global optional argument')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest="command", help='sub-command help')

# create the parser for the "status" command
parser_status = subparsers.add_parser('status', help='status help')

# create the parser for the "tail" command
parser_tail = subparsers.add_parser('tail', help='tail help')
parser_tail.add_argument('path', help='path to log')

print parser.parse_args()
```

The `dest` keyword of the `add_subparsers` ensures that you can still get the command name afterwards, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4575792/4042267) and in the documentation.

Example usage:

```
$ python script.py status   
Namespace(command='status', foo=False)

$ python script.py tail /tmp/some.log
Namespace(command='tail', foo=False, path='/tmp/some.log')
```

Note that any global argument needs to come before the command:

```
$ python script.py tail /tmp/some.log --foo
usage: PROG [-h] [--foo] {status,tail} ...
PROG: error: unrecognized arguments: --foo

$ python script.py --foo tail /tmp/some.log
Namespace(command='tail', foo=True, path='/tmp/some.log')
```

Comment: Didn't know about the sub-parser concept. Thanks.